# O que é Sargable argument?

Tags: banco-de-dados, query, terminologia

Em consultas a banco de dados qual é o conceito de um *sargable argument* (Search ARGument Able)?

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @bigown, ainda não, talvez eu precise fazer uma boa pesquisa e resumir em uma resposta. A pergunta está meio 'fraca'? da pra entender?

Comment: Acho que sim, ela não parece muito complicada :) Acho que só precisa ter alguém que saiba e queira responder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sei que esta pergunta já tem quase um ano mas penso que, ainda assim, talvez a resposta possa interessar a alguém.

Resumidamente um predicado ou condição é considerado *sargable* (Search ARGument Able) se o DBMS pode tirar partido de um índice para melhorar o tempo de execução de uma determinada query.

Uma típica situação que faz com que uma query seja *non-sargable* consiste em incluir na cláusula WHERE uma função que tem como parâmetro uma coluna. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_tabela
WHERE YEAR(ColunaData) = 2008
```

Nesta situação não é possível a utilização de um índice sobre a coluna ColunaData, ainda que o mesmo exista. Esta função será portanto avaliada para cada registo na tabela. Uma alternativa a usar seria:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_tabela
WHERE ColunaData >= '01-01-2008' AND ColunaData < '01-01-2009'
```

Outro exemplo que é usado muitas vezes:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_tabela
WHERE Field LIKE '%blah%'
```

Ou ainda:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_tabela
WHERE SUBSTRING(ColumnVarchar, 1, 6) = 'Joaquim'
```

Em alternativa poderia ser usado:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_tabela
WHERE ColumnVarchar LIKE 'Joaquim%'
```

Para exemplo final deixo o tratamento dos NULL com o qual nos deparamos quase diariamente

Como não fazer:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Tabela
WHERE ISNULL(ColunaNome, 'Manuel Joaquim') = 'Manuel Joaquim'
```

Versão correcta:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_tabela
WHERE ColunaNome= 'Manuel Joaquim' 
   OR ColunaNome IS NULL
```

Uma nota final. É de salientar que o conceito de *sargability* aplica-se não só á clausula WHERE mas também afecta o ORDER BY, GROUP BY e HAVING. 
Já o SELECT pode conter expressões *non-sargable* que isso não tem impacto na performance.