# Filtrar ano e mês PHP e MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Como trazer registro referente a *mês* e *ano* que usuário digitou (da forma abaixo não funcionou)?

```
function filtrarData($datap) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE YEAR(data_pago) = ? MONTH(data_pago) = ?";

    try {
    $com = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $com->bindValue(1, $datap->getDataPago());
    $com->bindValue(2, $datap->getDataPago());
    $com->execute();
    $resultado = $com->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->db = null;
    return $resultado;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die( $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Gostaria de receber esse valor de um *input date* e filtrar pelo ano e mês digitado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão o [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) passa o parâmetro como *string*, então você precisa converter na consulta o parâmetro recebido em *date*; além disso, você está comparando ano e mês (`year()` e `month()`) com datas inteiras, o que não dará certo. Tente o seguinte:

```
function filtrarData($datap) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE YEAR(data_pago) = YEAR(DATE(?)) MONTH(data_pago) = MONTH(DATE(?))";

    try {
    $com = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $com->bindValue(1, $datap->getDataPago());
    $com->bindValue(2, $datap->getDataPago());
    $com->execute();
    $resultado = $com->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->db = null;
    return $resultado;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die( $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

`YEAR(DATE(?))` pega apenas o ano de uma nova *data* criada com o parâmetro enviado.

---

Uma alternativa é fazer o controle via ***php***:

```
function filtrarData($datap) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE YEAR(data_pago) = ? MONTH(data_pago) = ?";

    try {
    $formatador = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $datap->getDataPago());

    $com = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $com->bindValue(1, $formatador->format("Y"));
    $com->bindValue(2, $formatador->format("m"));
    $com->execute();
    $resultado = $com->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->db = null;
    return $resultado;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die( $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

Baseado nas dicas dadas por [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco), seria válido para a performance da consulta remover o uso das funções (`year()` e `month()`) e adicionar esta validação como restrição da consulta:

```
function filtrarData($datap) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE data_pago >= ? AND data_pago <= ?";

    try {
    $formatador = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $datap->getDataPago());

    $com = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $com->bindValue(1, $formatador->format("Y-m-")."01"); //primeiro dia do mês
    $com->bindValue(2, date("Y-m-t", strtotime($datep))); //último dia do mês
    $com->execute();
    $resultado = $com->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->db = null;
    return $resultado;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die( $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Para melhor entendimento desta alteração, vale entender [**esta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21793/o-que-%C3%A9-sargable-argument)!!

Comment: Caso alguém precise resolver só com SQL: MySQL tem função de ultimo dia do mes, quando for resolver no lado SQL: `WHERE coluna BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(data_fixa,'%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(data_fixa);` - a fórmula não atrapalha neste caso pq nao é sobre a coluna, e sim sobre 1 valor fixo (é calculado uma vez só, pelo query planner).