# selecionar mês e ano de um campo datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql

Possuo um campo do tipo `datetime` e preciso fazer uma consulta baseado apenas no mês e no ano. Ao pesquisar, notei que existe a função `extract`, mas ela separa apenas um valor do `datetime`.

exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE EXTRACT(month from date_column) = 5
AND EXTRACT(year from date_column) = 2018;
```

Existe alguma função que faça esse *"extract"* de uma vez ao invés de usar o `AND`?

Comment: para fazer exatamente o que o EXTRACT faz na sua simplicidade não conheço, mas também não vejo motivo para ter. você poderia usar um sub string e compara uma parte da data mais isso chegar e ser uma gabiarra comparando o que o EXTRACT faz.

Comment: Você pode utilizar a função date_trunc('month', seu_campo_timestamp).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) no campo date, passando a formatação apenas para retornar o mês e o ano, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
DECLARE

data_exemplo DATE := TO_DATE('10/01/2005','DD/MM/YYYY');
data_exemplo_2 DATE := TO_DATE('13/03/1998','DD/MM/YYYY');
v_nome VARCHAR(30);

BEGIN

SELECT NOME
INTO v_nome
FROM PESSOA
WHERE TO_CHAR(data_nasc,'MM') = TO_CHAR(data_exemplo,'MM')
AND TO_CHAR(data_nasc,'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(data_exemplo_2,'YYYY');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Valor retornado: ' || v_nome);

END;
/
```

Segue o resultado da execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você também consegue usar o TO_CHAR passando o mês e o ano ao mesmo tempo (conforme abaixo), ai dependeria da sua necessidade.

```
SELECT NOME
INTO v_nome
FROM PESSOA
WHERE TO_CHAR(data_nasc,'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(data_exemplo,'MM/YYYY');
```

Bons estudos!

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de fazer isso seria checar o intervalo entre as datas.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE date_column >= '2018-05-01'
  AND date_column <= '2018-05-31';
```

**detalhe**: vale dar uma lida [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21793/o-que-%C3%A9-sargable-argument) e entender porque não usar funções tipo o `EXTRACT` no `where`.

Comment: mas qual o problema? se a data deve ter mês 5 e ano 2018, ela deve **obrigatoriamente** ser maior/igual 01/05/2018 e menor/igual 31/05/2018, não?!

Comment: releia a pergunta.

Comment: lida.. relida.. o que vi q poderia alterar era a data fixa; mas acredito que isto não invalide a resposta, já que na pergunta não está parametrizado.. no mais, do que entendi, a resposta é esta! caso esteja errado, por favor, editem a pergunta ou comentem algo que ajude, visto que ninguém respondeu!!

Comment: ele que uma função que faça tudo de uma vez tipo WHERE date_column = '2018-05'

Comment: entendi, mas também não conheço alguma função do tipo.. o mais próximo (considerando performance) acredito que seria isso que respondi