# Ordernar valores da tabela por Dia e Mes

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho esse Select abaixo:

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.codigo,
       a.codacesso,
       a.seqproduto,
       a.desccompleta,
       b.quantidade,
       b.data_vencimento,
       b.data_atual,
       b.observacao,
       b.usuario,
       b.estado,
       b.loja,
       a.medvdiageral,
       a.comprador,
       a.preco
  FROM master_datas_b a, master_coletores b
 WHERE b.tipo_acao IS NULL
   and a.comprador = :comprador
   and a.nroempresa = :loja
   and b.loja = :loja
   and estado = 'Ativo'
   and b.codigo = a.codacesso
   AND b.data_vencimento BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
       TO_DATE(:data2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   and b.quantidade > 0
 ORDER BY b.data_vencimento, b.codigo ASC
```

Ele está retornando os valores mas não da forma que preciso, ele está ordenando por dia, por exemplo:

```
12/11/2018
13/12/2018
14/11/2018
```

Eu preciso que faça a ordem por dia e mês e dezembro aparecesse somente no final da lista..

Comment: Segundo seu exemplo a ordenação está correta. Ordenação ASC é crescente, então a data 13/12/2018 realmente vem após a 12/11/2018.

Comment: problema é que está assim 12/11/2018 - 13/12/2018 - 14/11/2018

Comment: Editei sua pergunta pra acrescentar o exemplo da forma que colocou no comentário.

Answer (score 1):

Pra resolver, a forma mais fácil seria converter o campo para tipo data usando [`to_date()`](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date) e ordenar (pelo problema, seu campo deve ser `varchar`):

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.codigo,
       a.codacesso,
       a.seqproduto,
       a.desccompleta,
       b.quantidade,
       b.data_vencimento,
       b.data_atual,
       b.observacao,
       b.usuario,
       b.estado,
       b.loja,
       a.medvdiageral,
       a.comprador,
       a.preco
  FROM master_datas_b a, master_coletores b
 WHERE b.tipo_acao IS NULL
   and a.comprador = :comprador
   and a.nroempresa = :loja
   and b.loja = :loja
   and estado = 'Ativo'
   and b.codigo = a.codacesso
   AND b.data_vencimento BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
       TO_DATE(:data2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   and b.quantidade > 0
 ORDER BY TO_DATE(b.data_vencimento, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), b.codigo ASC
```

detalhe: pelo fato do campo ser tipo *string*, você com certeza terá perda de performance para consultas, já que terá de usar funções de conversão no `where`, e isso compromete bastante, como pode ser visto [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21793/64073).

Answer (score 1):

Eu descobri o problema, na verdade é uma estilização do bootstrap.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
```

ele referência pela primeira coluna da tabela, e a primeira era o código.
eu removi o 'datatable'

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable">
```

e agora ele está ordenando de forma correta, fica a dica :P