# Filtro usando apenas mês e ano no SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, query, servidor, data

Estou precisando montar um select, no qual o filtro seja usado apenas o mês e o ano  nos parâmetros.

Esse é o select que eu tô usando atualmente, mas preciso que o 'dia' não influencie na minha busca.

```
SELECT NOME_CLIENTE, 
       COUNT(NUMERO_BILHETE) AS 'QUANTIDADE DE BILHETES' 
  FROM BANCO.DBO.CLIENTES
 WHERE DATA_EMBARQUE BETWEEN '2017-01-15' 
   AND '2017-01-30'  
 GROUP BY NOME_CLIENTE
```

Comment: (1) O que significa "_o dia não influencie em minha busca_"? (2) Como está declarada a coluna `DATA_EMBARQUE`?

Comment: Ele está como DATE. Eu queria usar como parâmetros apenas o mês e o ano para realizar a busca.

Comment: @CarolineTelles, alguma das repostas resolveu? o que precisa ser melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que a forma mais simples seja usando a *formatação correta* do tipo `date` ([**aqui**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) tem uma lista com os códigos e os formatos utilizáveis para datas):

```
SELECT NOME_CLIENTE, 
       COUNT(NUMERO_BILHETE) AS 'QUANTIDADE DE BILHETES' 
  FROM BANCO.DBO.CLIENTES
 WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(6), DATA_EMBARQUE, 112) = '2017-01' --substituir por @ano_mes_param
 GROUP BY NOME_CLIENTE
```

Outra alternativa seria pegar as primeiras posições da data para comparação utilizando o [`LEFT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
WHERE LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATA_EMBARQUE, 112), 6)
```

---

**EDITADO**

após comentário nesta resposta (*"Encapsular coluna com função não é uma boa prática, pois torna o código non sargable. Vide artigo [Construindo códigos T-SQL eficientes: Sargability](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)"*), acredito que a melhor solução seria a seguinte (levando em consideração *não usar funções no where*):

```
DECLARE @DATA_INI DATE, @DATA_FIM DATE

SELECT @DATA_INI = '2018-01-01'
SELECT @DATA_FIM = EOMONTH(@DATA_INI)

SELECT NOME_CLIENTE, 
       COUNT(NUMERO_BILHETE) AS 'QUANTIDADE DE BILHETES' 
  FROM BANCO.DBO.CLIENTES
 WHERE DATA_EMBARQUE >= @DATA_INI
   AND DATA_EMBARQUE <= @DATA_FIM
 GROUP BY NOME_CLIENTE
```

Usei o [EOMONTH()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) pra poder pegar o último dia do mês; mas também pode pegar o dia *1* do mês seguinte e checar se `DATA_EMBARQUE < @DATA_FIM` (para isso, usaria `DATEADD(month, 1, DATA_EMBARQUE)`).

Comment: @JoséDiz valeu a observação, adicionei uma solução que acredito ser mais performática

Comment: Show! Às vezes, por um pequeno detalhe a execução do código pode tornar-se lenta.

Answer (score 1):

Eis uma solução em que se informa apenas o mês e ano e o código se encarrega de montar o filtro.

```
-- código #1 v2
declare @Ano smallint, @Mês tinyint;

-- informe o ano (formato aaaa) e mês (formato mm)
set @Ano= 2017;
set @Mês= 1;

---
-- geração automática das variáveis de filtro
declare @D1 date, @D2 date;
set dateformat dmy;
set @D1= cast ('1/' + cast (@Mês as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast (@Ano as char(4)) as date);
set @D2= dateadd (day, -1, dateadd (month, +1, @D1));

--
SELECT NOME_CLIENTE, 
       count (NUMERO_BILHETE) as [QUANTIDADE DE BILHETES]
  from BANCO.DBO.CLIENTES
  where DATA_EMBARQUE between @D1 and @D2
  group by NOME_CLIENTE;
```

Para evitar a conversão implícita, as variáveis `@D1` e `@D2` devem ser declaradas com o mesmo tipo de dados da coluna `DATA_EMBARQUE`. Detalhes no artigo [Os perigos da conversão implícita (1)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/os-perigos-da-conversao-implicita-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Basta filtrar as datas entre o primeiro e último dia do mês. Não precisa utilizar funções para filtrar mês e ano sendo que pode utilizar essa lógica.

```
--Primeiro dia de Janeiro (01/01/2017) até o último dia de Janeiro (31/01/2017)
SELECT NOME_CLIENTE, 
       COUNT(NUMERO_BILHETE) AS 'QUANTIDADE DE BILHETES' 
  FROM BANCO.DBO.CLIENTES
 WHERE DATA_EMBARQUE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
 GROUP BY NOME_CLIENTE
```

Caso queira utilizar funções para este fim, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT NOME_CLIENTE, 
       COUNT(NUMERO_BILHETE) AS 'QUANTIDADE DE BILHETES' 
  FROM BANCO.DBO.CLIENTES
 WHERE MONTH(DATA_EMBARQUE) = 1 
   AND YEAR(DATA_EMBARQUE) = 2017
 GROUP BY NOME_CLIENTE
```

`MONTH(data)` você filtra pelo mês e `YEAR(data)` filtra pelo ano.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT NOME_CLIENTE, 
       COUNT(NUMERO_BILHETE) AS 'QUANTIDADE DE BILHETES' 
  FROM BANCO.DBO.CLIENTES
 WHERE YEAR(DATA_EMBARQUE) >= YEAR(@DataInicial) 
   AND MONTH(DATA_EMBARQUE) >= MONTH(@DataInicial)
   AND YEAR(DATA_EMBARQUE) <= YEAR(@DataFinal) 
   AND MONTH(DATA_EMBARQUE) <= MONTH(@DataFinal)
GROUP BY NOME_CLIENTE
```

Comment: sem querer ser ofensivo mas essa seria a solução mais custosa já que chamaria até 8 funções por registro na consulta. Dá uma lida [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21793/o-que-%C3%A9-sargable-argument/60667#60667), vale a pena entender ;)