# Select por período

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho esse select.

```
SELECT 5125 matricula, CONCAT(fum.nomeguerra, ' / ' , fuc.nomeguerra) nomeguerra, date_format(es.data, '%d/%m/%Y') as data, es.semana, es.horarios, es.linha
FROM escala es
LEFT JOIN funcionario fuc ON fuc.matricula = es.matr_cobr
LEFT JOIN funcionario fum ON fum.matricula = es.matr_moto       
WHERE (matr_moto = 5125 or matr_cobr = 5125)
  AND es.data BETWEEN curdate() AND CURRENT_DATE()+6
ORDER BY es.data
```

No banco tenho todos os meses e preciso que ele retorne apenas o dia atual mais 7 dia pra frente. Isso funciona perfeitamente se essa contagem for a partir do início do mês. Se for no caso no dia 28 do mês ele só pega até o fim do mês, ele não passa para o próximo mês.

linha onde ele faz essa checagem `AND es.data BETWEEN curdate() AND CURRENT_DATE()+6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a forma mais indicada pra fazer isso seja usando o [`DATE_ADD()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp):

```
SELECT 5125 matricula, CONCAT(fum.nomeguerra, ' / ' , fuc.nomeguerra) nomeguerra, date_format(es.data, '%d/%m/%Y') as data, es.semana, es.horarios, es.linha
FROM escala es
LEFT JOIN funcionario fuc ON fuc.matricula = es.matr_cobr
LEFT JOIN funcionario fum ON fum.matricula = es.matr_moto       
WHERE (matr_moto = 5125 or matr_cobr = 5125)
  AND es.data BETWEEN curdate() AND DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
ORDER BY es.data
```

---

Vale salientar que desta forma sua consulta utiliza *funções no where*, algo que [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21793/o-que-%C3%A9-sargable-argument/60667#60667) explica bem que isso deve ser evitado por questões de performance.

Sendo assim, caso esteja usando essa consulta dentro de alguma *procedure* ou apenas no banco de dados, aconselho criar uma variável para armazenar o valor da(s) data(s):

```
SELECT @data_atual := curdate(), @data_final := DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 DAY);

SELECT 5125 matricula, CONCAT(fum.nomeguerra, ' / ' , fuc.nomeguerra) nomeguerra, date_format(es.data, '%d/%m/%Y') as data, es.semana, es.horarios, es.linha
FROM escala es
LEFT JOIN funcionario fuc ON fuc.matricula = es.matr_cobr
LEFT JOIN funcionario fum ON fum.matricula = es.matr_moto       
WHERE (matr_moto = 5125 or matr_cobr = 5125)
  AND es.data >= @data_atual 
  AND es.data <= @data_final
ORDER BY es.data
```

obs: removi também o `between`, pensando na performance.

Comment: Massa, funcionou perfeitamente.