# Erro ao executar uma subquery no sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

Estou tentando retornar valores onde a data seja entre dois campos da minha pagina
esse campo e o max(campo)

A consulta é essa:

```
SELECT      COD_SECAO
        ,   SECAO
        ,   CHAPA
        ,   NOME
        ,   DTNASCIMENTO
        ,   DATAADMISSAO
        ,   INICIO_PERIODO
        ,   FIM_PERIODO
        ,   INICPROGFERIAS1
        ,   FIMPROGFERIAS1
        ,   (INICIO_PERIODO + 365) AS LIMITE1
        ,   (INICIO_PERIODO + 670) AS LIMITE2  
FROM    ( 
            SELECT  PSECAO.CODIGO       AS COD_SECAO
                ,   PSECAO.DESCRICAO    AS SECAO 
                ,   PFUNC.CHAPA         AS CHAPA 
                ,   PFUNC.NOME          AS NOME 
                ,   PFUNC.CODSITUACAO   AS SITUACAO 
                ,   (
                        SELECT  MAX(PFHSTFER.DTINIPERAQUIS) 
                        FROM    PFHSTFER 
                        WHERE   PFHSTFER.CODCOLIGADA    = PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA 
                            AND PFHSTFER.CHAPA          = PFUNC.CHAPA 
                            AND PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA       = 1 
                            AND PFHSTFER.DTFIMGOZO      IS NULL 
                    )                   AS INICIO_PERIODO 
                ,   ( 
                        SELECT  MAX(PFHSTFER.DTFIMPERAQUIS) 
                        FROM    PFHSTFER 
                        WHERE   PFHSTFER.CODCOLIGADA    = PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA 
                            AND PFHSTFER.CHAPA          = PFUNC.CHAPA 
                            AND PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA       = 1 
                            AND PFHSTFER.DTFIMGOZO      IS NULL 
                        HAVING  (MAX(PFHSTFER.DTFIMPERAQUIS) BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-30')
                    )                   AS FIM_PERIODO 
                ,   PFUNC.INICPROGFERIAS1 
                ,   PFUNC.FIMPROGFERIAS1 
                ,   PFUNC.DATAADMISSAO 
                ,   PPESSOA.DTNASCIMENTO 
            FROM    PFUNC 
                ,   PSECAO 
                ,   PPESSOA  
            WHERE   PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA               = PSECAO.CODCOLIGADA  
                AND PFUNC.CODSECAO                  = PSECAO.CODIGO 
                AND PFUNC.CODPESSOA                 = PPESSOA.CODIGO 
                AND PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA               = 1 
                AND PFUNC.CODSITUACAO               NOT IN ('D', 'I', 'T', 'P', 'U', 'L', 'R') 
                AND PFUNC.CODTIPO                   IN ('N', 'T') 
                AND SUBSTRING(PFUNC.CODSECAO, 7, 2) != '99' 
                AND SUBSTRING(PFUNC.CODSECAO, 3, 3) IN ('004')   
                AND PFUNC.CODSECAO                  = '1.004.07.01.01574.001'   
        ) X 
ORDER BY    LIMITE2 ASC
        ,   COD_SECAO
        ,   NOME
```

O problema é que `fim_periodo` esta retornando nulo, quando na verdade ao tirar o `between` ele retorna os valores maximos dos campos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que a melhor forma de fazer isso é não usando o `having`. Como está trazendo apenas um campo, podes deixar o filtro no `where` mesmo:

```
SELECT MAX(PFHSTFER.DTFIMPERAQUIS) 
  FROM PFHSTFER 
 WHERE PFHSTFER.CODCOLIGADA = PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA 
   AND PFHSTFER.CHAPA = PFUNC.CHAPA 
   AND PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA = 1 
   AND PFHSTFER.DTFIMGOZO IS NULL 
   AND PFHSTFER.DTFIMPERAQUIS BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-30'
```

Detalhe: usar funções nos filtros pode acabar com a performance da consulta, como explicado [nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21793/o-que-%C3%A9-sargable-argument/60667#60667). Nesse caso, você está usando o `between` na *subconsulta* pra cada linha de retorno, pesquisando na tabela `PFHSTFER` - caso ela seja muito grande, a consulta pode ficar lenta.

Comment: Deu na mesma, o que fiz agora foi como data final é a data de admissão + 730 fiz isso e retornou o resultado que queria. Não foi o mais bonito mas funcionou.

Comment: é o que importa.. xD

Comment: estava pensando.. qual o formato de data no banco? acredito que se fosse esse problema daria erro ao tentar acessar o mês _30_, mas..

Comment: exibição dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss datetime 06/02/1999 00:00:00.000 para consulta basta yyyy/mm/dd